# Jinja2 debugging

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have quite a number of templates all in `jinja2` in my flask app. The problem I have, `Werkzeug Debugger` cannot point me to the exact location of the bug, it only flashes out a template syntax error `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected`. Is there a way I can reconfigure it to point me to the exact location of the bug?...otherwise this is a pain in the bone to debug.

I have looked through my scripts but they all seem fine. I have even tried commenting out some to no success. And yes I added the following into my configuration file `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False` after doing rounds of research.

My stack trace:

`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected
Traceback (most recent call last)

```
File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app

response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router

return original_handler(e)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

raise value

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router

return original_handler(e)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

raise value

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request

return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/app/main/index/views.py", line 24, in index

search_form=search_form)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template

context, ctx.app)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render

rv = template.render(context)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render

return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render

return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise

raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/app/templates/base.html", line 48, in template

<li {% - if request.path == url_for('user.index') %} class="active"{%- endif -%} ><a

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1005, in render

return concat(self.root_render_func(self.new_context(vars)))

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/app/main/index/templates/index.html", line 1, in top-level template code

{% extends "base.html" %}

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise

raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/app/templates/base.html", line 48, in template

<li {% - if request.path == url_for('user.index') %} class="active"{%- endif -%} ><a

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 497, in _parse

return Parser(self, source, name, encode_filename(filename)).parse()

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 901, in parse

result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 883, in subparse

rv = self.parse_statement()

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement

return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 268, in parse_block

node.body = self.parse_statements(('name:endblock',), drop_needle=True)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements

result = self.subparse(end_tokens)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 883, in subparse

rv = self.parse_statement()

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement

return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 223, in parse_if

drop_needle=True)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements

result = self.subparse(end_tokens)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 883, in subparse

rv = self.parse_statement()

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 125, in parse_statement

self.fail('tag name expected', token.lineno)

File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 59, in fail

raise exc(msg, lineno, self.name, self.filename)

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected`
```

If I can get help, in terms of pointing me exactly where the jinja2 template error originates from, I will be so grateful...bring on the hacks, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the line causing problems in your stack trace:

```
File "/doka/Desktop/Python_projects/flask_collection/flaskbook/app/templates/base.html", line 48, in template
<li {% - if request.path == url_for('user.index') %} class="active"{%- endif -%} ><a
```

As Jinja docs say:

> You must not add whitespace between the tag and the minus sign.
>
> valid:
>
> `{%- if foo -%}...{% endif %}`
>
> invalid:
>
> `{% - if foo - %}...{% endif %}`

More: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/

Comment: I never spotted that for a long time. Thank you for the pointer.